# Aws open port to another instance but not publicly

Tags: amazon-web-services, port, vpc

I didn't understand which rule I have to setup in my vpc to make the postgres port available only to other instances in the same vpc.

Let me clarify:

172.30.0.183 is my database.

172.30.0.207 instance A

172.30.0.165 instance B

They are in the same VPC. 
If I include an inbound rule to the port 5432(postgres) binded to 0.0.0.0/0, I can access my database from the Internet, but I dont want that.
I just want my instances A and B to be able to connect with it.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need two security groups to do this properly.

The first one doesn't need any ingress rules.  Let's call it "DatabaseClient".  Attach it to instances A and B.

Now create another group.  Open port 5432 to any instance running under the "DatabaseClient" group.  Call it "DatabaseServer".  Associate it with the postgres server.

You're done.

Here's an example of how to do this via cloudformation - you'll need to know the VPC id to run it.

```
{
  "Description" : "Postgres access",

  "Parameters" : {
    "VpcId" : {
      "Type" : "String"
    }
  },

  "Resources" : {

    "PGClient" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
      "Properties" : {
        "VpcId" : { "Ref" : "VpcId" },
        "GroupDescription" : "Associate with instances that need db access."
      }
    },

    "PGServer" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
      "Properties" : {
        "VpcId" : { "Ref" : "VpcId" },
        "GroupDescription" : ".",
        "SecurityGroupIngress" : [
          {
            "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
            "FromPort" : "5432",
            "ToPort" : "5432",
            "SourceSecurityGroupId" : { "Ref" : "PGClient" }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to use cloudformation for this, you can create the DatabaseClient security group first, then when you create or edit your DatabaseServer security group, reference the DatabaseClient security group as a "Custom IP" in the Source.